# How to sync Firebase Database containing product data (Picture, Price) to show up on website Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, firebase-realtime-database

We have a Firebase database connected with an APP which we want to convert to a website now. Laravel is nice frame work but unfortunately unable to sync the existing database to show up on the website as is. End goal is that any  changes through an APP should reflect on the website and vice versa. Existing database include the product price, picture, ability for users to message each other , user authentication. In essence it is almost a complete market place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use data from the Firebase Realtime Database in a web app/site, consider simply [using its JavaScript SDK in your web application](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).

Doing so allows you app to directly read data from the database, instead of having to set up a web server in Laravel.

To ensure that your users only get access to data they're authorized for, you'll want to [use Firebase's security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security). These are enforced on the Firebase server, so once you configure them correctly, there's no way for anyone to bypass them.